# Adding two time duration values

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an app script code that adds values in two columns and display the result in a third column.i.e column B value(time duration) is added to column D(time duration) and the result is displayed in column E. But my code shows error what to do

```
function adder()
 {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet5');
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
 var cell = sheet.getRange('B1:B'+lastRow).getValues();
 var data = sheet.getRange('D1:D'+lastRow).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++){
     var value1 = cell[i][0];
     var value2 = data[i][0];
     var range = sheet.getRange('E'+(i+1)).setFormula(value1+value2);
     var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(range.getValue()), 'GMT', 'dd/MM/yyyy 
                         HH:mm:ss');
     }
     sheet.getRange('E' + (i+1).toString()).setValue(formattedDate);
   }
```

the screen shoot of error has been uploaded to[image: ERROR message]

```
      function dateAdd() 
         {
         var ss = 
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet5');
        var range = ss.getRange('E23').setFormula('D23+B23');
        var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(range.getValue(), 'GMT', 
                                        'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
         }
```

The above code is working for a single row, I want to set it in a Loop.

Comment: all the values in column E is displayed as ERROR only

Comment: You add 2 durations, then do you want to change the result to date? I think you must involve the column A too.

Comment: Please check new Date(range.getValue()), the range are durations value

Comment: @user11982798 actually the result is duration only.I have tried new Date(range.getValue) also still I am getting error. I want the result in hh:mm

Comment: Please try use logger.log to your range.getvalue to check your result of durations value adding. And for HH:mm, you don't need dd/mm/yyyy in your format, I think.

Comment: If you please, you can share your sheet here.

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vWab8csRRyop1YMjYyXxI6opn2_bsQJzBIXTPzG2nmE

Comment: I have added a code that will work for single row only. I want to apply it for all rows

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Reformat the duration columns to "#.##########" just before reading the data and use Range.getDisplayValue()s and then format back to "[h]:mm:ss" you don't run into the string versus number problem.

```
function runThree() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  var rgB=sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var rgD=sh.getRange(2,4,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var rgE=sh.getRange(2,5,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  rgE.clearContent();
  rgB.setNumberFormat("#.##########");//increased precision improves round off
  rgD.setNumberFormat("#.##########");
  var vB=rgB.getDisplayValues();
  var vD=rgD.getDisplayValues();
  rgB.setNumberFormat("[h]:mm:ss");
  rgD.setNumberFormat("[h]:mm:ss");
  var vE=[];
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  for(var i=0;i<vB.length;i++){
    var sum=vB[i][0]+vD[i][0];
    vE.push([Number(vB[i][0])+Number(vD[i][0])%24]);     
  }
  rgE.setValues(vE);
  rgE.setNumberFormat("[h]:mm:ss")
}
```

Sheet 5 before running:

[image]

Sheet 5 after running:

[image]

I was surprised to find out that the duration will display hour values as high as 1150 hours.

Comment: My new column values start at second row, instead of starting at first if i declare ve =[ ] it gives error as data and range not matching

Comment: I just made a small change give it a try see if it works I’m on my cell phone right now so I’ll get back to my desktop and test it but I think that should fix your problem.

Comment: I tested the change it looks okay to me.

Comment: where did you make the change and can u tell the logic

Comment: `var rgB=sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var rgD=sh.getRange(2,4,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var rgE=sh.getRange(2,5,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);`

Answer (score 1):

Your failure is value1+ value2 will become text

So I make a little modifiction of your script to be (+0 and +8 in mine , change as your zone I think) :

```
function adder()
 {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Log');
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
   var cell = sheet.getRange('C2:C'+lastRow).getValues();
   var data = sheet.getRange('D2:D'+lastRow).getValues();
   for (var i = 0; i < lastRow-1; i++){
       var value1 = cell[i][0];
       var value2 = data[i][0];
       var d = value1;
       d.setHours(value1.getHours()+value2.getHours()+0);
       d.setMinutes(value1.getMinutes()+value2.getMinutes()+8);
       var range = sheet.getRange('E'+(i+2)).setValue(d);
   }
 }
```

[image: Pic]

my Update:

```
function adder()
 {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Log');
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
   var cell = sheet.getRange('B1:B'+lastRow).getValues();
   var data = sheet.getRange('D1:D'+lastRow).getValues();
   for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++){
     var value1 = cell[i][0];
       var value2 = data[i][0];
       var d = value1;
       d.setHours(value1.getHours()+value2.getHours()+0);
       d.setMinutes(value1.getMinutes()+value2.getMinutes()+8);
       var range = sheet.getRange('E'+(i+1)).setValue(d);
   }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: while executing it says Cannot find function setHours in object 1

Comment: You must ensure that the script change as your situation, mine C & D, yours B and D, you must change it, and setHours can't be recognize by string, only date and time.

Comment: and in my sample from A2 but in yours from A1, so you must revise it

Comment: i changed the sample to B1 and D1 column still it says like that. and it is  not getting affected at first row it says in my case 1:50:00 AM

Comment: Your sheet can't be accessed (private), so I can't do check it.         d.setHours(value1.getHours()+value2.getHours()+0);
d.setMinutes(value1.getMinutes()+value2.getMinutes()+8); +0 and + 8 you must check and change it.